# Operações bit a bit (XOR)

Tags: c, operadores, bits

```
#include <stdio.h>


void main(){

    int a = 356, b = 3;
    printf("%d\n", a ^ b); /*


system("pause");
}
```

Alguém me explica por que esse `xor` dá 359? A conversão para binário fica:

```
101100100 --> 356
11 --> 3
```

Como eu comparo esses 2 valores? Para ser positivo somente uma das entradas pode ser positiva correto?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 3):

O *xor* é só uma soma sem o "vai um":

```
101100100 -> 356
000000011 -> 3
---------
101100111 -> 359
```

Sempre que achar 0 e 0 dá 0, sempre que achar 0 e 1 ou 1 e 0 dá 1 e sempre que achar 1 e 1 dá 0.

Então a comparação dos bits depende da forma exata de como é tratado na arquitetura específica, esses bits aí de cima não parecem considerar sinal. Mas o *xor* opera exatamente como na matemática se ambos forem positivos (0) então dá positivo, se forem ambos negativos (1) dá positivo (0) e se forem diferentes dá negativo (1).

Todas as operações matemáticas no computador se dão nos bits, a forma de cada operação fazer é que muda. E na verdade **todas** operações do computador são feitas através de portas lógicas *and*, *or* e *not*. Até existem algumas portas otimizadas que conseguem fazer algo um pouco mais sofisticado, mas não muito, então existe porta *xor* também que simplifica alguma operação e não precisa mais de uma porta (em arquiteturas muito simples para ter um *xor* precisa de mais de uma porta).

Quero reforçar que isso nem costuma ser assim de verdade dentro de um computador, essa é uma forma abstrata que usamos para entender melhor o que está acontecendo, inclusive porque cada arquitetura faz de forma específica diferente.

Embora tudo seja feito nos bits pelo computador, isso não é algo que você costuma precisar saber a não ser que esteja realmente operando em bits que por acaso estão no mesmo dado. Você trabalha com números. Não existem números binários, decimais ou hexadecimais, como alguns acham que existe, existem apenas números (nem textos existem, ou outras informações, só números, mas nem tudo vemos como se fossem números). Quase sempre um humano só quer saber de **ver** os números na forma decimal, e computadores **sempre** operam nos bits. Ao contrário do que alguns acham não há conversão para trabalhar com um jeito ou outro, existe conversão quando você entra um dado no computador (eles viram bits) e quando eles serão mostrados de alguma forma para uma pessoa ver (geralmente serão **mostrados** como decimal, mas pode mostrar de diversas outras formas), mas unidades de contagem numéricas existem no mundo sem olhar o jeito que ele está escrito ou representado.

Aqui eu te mostro uma outra forma de indicar o número que você conhece como três (opa, acabei de escrever mais uma forma):

[image: 3 patos de borracha]

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Esse operadores lógicos tipo o XOR tbm funcionam com hexadecimal ? ou só binario ?

Comment: Ele funciona com números, os bits são só uma forma abstrata de entender, não existem números binários, hexadecimais, decimais, como você acha que existem, só existe número.